# SQL-like query with timediff

Tags: python, pandas

**disclosure, this a super long-winded question, I'm just trying to give y'all the full run-through of what I have so there's little confusion.**

I have a dataset where I am attempting to tag certain rows if there is another row with a different type present within a certain time range and having some keys. See below:

| k1 | k2 | time | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | alpha | 12:30:00 | A |
| foo | beta | 12:45:00 | A |
| foo | alpha | 13:30:00 | B |
| foo | beta | 13:00:00 | B |

The rules for my "matching" are as follows:

1. The types for the compared rows need to be different (i.e. only compare rows where one's type is `A` and the other's is `B`)
2. The keys `k1, k2` need to match
3. The absolute difference in time between the rows needs to be at most 30 minutes

Given these rules, I want to return the following:

| k1 | k2 | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | alpha | false |
| foo | beta | true |

My method for implementing this currently looks like this, and is loosely based off how I would do an equivalent SQL query:

1. Separate the dataframe into two dataframes with rows of type `A` and `B` respectively, yielding (from this toy dataset):

`df_A`:

| k1 | k2 | time | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | alpha | 12:30:00 | A |
| foo | beta | 12:45:00 | A |

`df_B`:

| k1 | k2 | time | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | alpha | 13:30:00 | B |
| foo | beta | 13:00:00 | B |

2. Merge the dataframes `k1, k2`, yielding:

| k1 | k2 | time.a | type.a | time.b | type.b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | alpha | 12:30:00 | A | 13:30:00 | B |
| foo | beta | 12:45:00 | A | 13:00:00 | B |

3. Compare the times to determine if there is a `<=30min` timedelta between the two columns, and generate a new column `match` based on whether that criteria is true or false:

| k1 | k2 | time.a | type.a | time.b | type.b | match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | alpha | 12:30:00 | A | 13:30:00 | B | false |
| foo | beta | 12:45:00 | A | 13:00:00 | B | true |

4. Finally, keep just the stuff I want (`k1, k2, match`):

| k1 | k2 | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | alpha | false |
| foo | beta | true |

The only problem with my current approach is that, in my actual dataset, it's generating more matches because I believe it's creating a cross-product-like merge that's matching each qualifying instance of `type == B` to each qualifying instance of `type == A`. How do I change this behavior to just match it at least once, and then throw out any other matches that may occur? (I just want to know if there is at least one instance where a match occurs for this set of keys.)

Comment: is it possible that A will always be less than B? if so, you can generate an extra time column and use an interval index

Comment: @sammywemmy No, but that won't matter - I'm fine with the absolute interval time (meaning before or after) within the 30 minutes.

Comment: ok, maybe pd.merge_asof, with the tolerance parameter?